# I'm trying to find and match a word/string and get the value after the comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a cascading list (dynamic - could be 10 or 100) and I need to find and match a specific word/string and grab the value after the comma(see below)

---

eddy,Triangle

joe,Drum

sarah,Keyboard

jill,Guitar

bob,Bass

---

As an example, I want to find and match the string sarah and grab the word Keyboard, any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: What is source of this list...all you have shown is some text written in question, not a data or code format we can work with. Also what have you tried and what research have you done. It's not hard to do basic research on how to break apart strings

Comment: That's because its all on a blank page in a <pre> tag

Comment: At least put it into a structure that allows iterating collection to inspect each item, either as array or repeating html elements. To be honest it doesn't seem you have done any research into this and are expecting this to be a tutorial site which it is not. You are expected to do the basic research yourself before asking questions. Break it into parts...string comparison and manipulation , iterating a collection etc

Comment: I wonder how all the other people managed to work it out

Comment: The point is your question shows no research effort at all. This is not a code writing or tutorial service. There is no reason you shouldn't have been able to research this enough to be able to come up with a code starting point...not expect others to do all the work for you. regardless of those answers that is not how this site works as outlined in the help center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the string after `sarah,`:

```js
str = $('pre').text();

re = new RegExp('sarah,(.*)')
console.log(str.match(re)[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
eddy,Triangle
joe,Drum
sarah,Keyboard
jill,Guitar
bob,Bass
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks dude, awesome work but I cannot put this list into a string

Answer (score 0):

You want like this?

```js
var str = $("#pre").text();
var arr = str.match(/sarah/);
console.log(arr[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="pre">eddy,Triangle 
joe,Drum 
sarah,Keyboard 
jill,Guitar 
bob,Bass</pre>
```

Comment: Just to add that as he needs the word after the, he should do: `arr.forEach(function(element){
result.push(element.split(',')[1]);
})`

Comment: That's not to say that the word is always going to be keyboard

Comment: [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) + `document.querySelectorAll` + `.match(/.../)`

Comment: Just mind creating a variable result before the arr.forEach

Comment: Thanks dude, very helpful